# My web app's menu shows an unwanted margin

Tags: css, webview, menubar

My web-view site, including menu, content and product, are showing correctly in Chrome and Firefox. However whenever I open my app the menu bar does not work as expected. It shows an unwanted margin between the product image and details.

The image below shows the issue:

[image]

How can I reduce this margin?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to your question. It's hard to help with debugging when we can't see what your current code is doing.

Comment: Thanks dharman.. it's benn solved itself..it was may be website chach problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dharman.. it's benn solved itself..it was may be website chach problem!

Comment: @Abdus, this CSS is will break the website layout because it will remove `padding` & `margin` from all the element. Not recommended.